# How to secure mail.domain.com with let's encrypt in directadmin using dovcot?

Tags: email, ssl, lets-encrypt, directadmin

When generating certificate via directadmin using letsencrypt for mail.domain.com, directadmin told me that it generated a certificate called:

```
letsencrypt.key
```

But in order to make the mail.domain.com contains the certificate, I have to edit the dovcot config like below:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/YOURSITE/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/YOURSITE/privkey.pem
```

But as shown above dovcot only take 2 parameters for certs and I only have letsencrypt.key

How do I point this certificate in dovcot so, that it will use let's encrypt certs ?

UPDATE:
I read that the built-in feature letsencrypt in DA actually combined the cert into one. I search Google and redirected to a site that we can manually install the DA letsencrypt so that it will generate 3 files for certs where I can use to link in dovcot.

So in order to do this do I have to disable the built in feature of DA Let's encrypt?

The URL: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/letsencrypt-support-directadmin-control-panel/

Is this the best way? What about the renewal process? Will directadmin handle the cert's renewal process or we need to create cronjob for that ? I'm lost.

My aim is just to enable certificate for the mail.domain.com (using let's encrypt) so when I log in using 3rd party email client, it would not complain about invalid certs.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about mail_sni someone pointed out that I should use this to make it work. Following this documentation, everything is working:

http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=56297